# get variable from ajax not working

Tags: php, ajax, get

I try to pass two variables using ajax after success :

```
$('#sendrangedt').click(function(){
      var params = $('#paramexport').serialize();
      var lowdt = $('#startdate').val();
      var enddt = $('#enddate').val();
      $.ajax({
         type:"post",
         url:"doserver.php",
         data:params,
         cache :false,
         async :false,
         success : function(result) {
            $('#excelink').replaceWith(
               '<div id="excelink"><a href="export2.php?start='+lowdt+'&end='+enddt+'" >Export Data</a></div>'
            );
            $('#startdate,#enddate').val("");
            return this;
            }
```

i can see the parameter pass to export2.php

```
export2.php?start=2017-11-29&end=2017-11-29
```

Beside that, after pass the parameter to export2.php i want to echo the variable.But the page result empty.

```
if(isset($_GET['start'])){
    $datestart = $_GET['start'];

    function showvalue($datestart){
       echo "ok";
    }
}
else{ 
   echo "not ok";
}
```

Comment: how do you know it falls to success? where is error section in your ajax block?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the variable through on success function or define them in success function to access.

```
success : function(result) {
            var lowdt = $('#startdate').val();
            var enddt = $('#enddate').val();
            $('#excelink').replaceWith(
               '<div id="excelink"><a href="export2.php?start='+lowdt+'&end='+enddt+'" >Export Data</a></div>'
            );
            $('#startdate,#enddate').val("");
            return this;
            }
```

Comment: @nunu Do you see the values when you hover the mouse on the link? let me know please.

Comment: `export2.php?start=` based on your answer